# Error starting visual studio after installing update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After installing visual studio update 3. I receive an operation fail:

`An item with the same key has already been added` message.

I can't open any projects or do any work. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: I refer you to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406071/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-while-installing-nuget-package

Comment: My problem is with visual studio ide itself, i am unable to load any projects.